# Is there a way to include a column from one table in many other tables (while maintaining consistency) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build a database (in PostgreSQL 9.6.6) that allows for one "master column" (`items.id`) to be replicated in to many (automatically generated) tables (e.g. `rank1.id, rank2.id, rank3.id, ...`). Only `items` will have `INSERT`'s (or `DELETE`'s) performed and when they are the newly added `id`'s should also show up (or be removed) in the `rankX` table(s). To be more concrete:

```
items:
id | name | description

rank1:
id | rank

rank2:
id | rank

...
```

Where the `id`'s are always the same, and there is *always* the same number of rows in each of the tables. The `rankX.rank` values, however, will be different (imagine users ranking how funny a series of images are -- the images all have the same `id`'s but different users might rank them differently).

What I was thinking was that when a new user was added and a new `rankX` table created I would do the following:

1. Have `rankX.id` referencing a foreign key `items.id` (with `ON DELETE CASCADE`)
2. Copy any `items.id` that already exist
3. Auto-generate a trigger function that mirrors the `INSERT`'s to `items` to the `rankX` table

This seems cumbersome and wasteful of space since *all* of the `xxxx.id` columns are identical and I will end up with hundreds or thousands of trigger functions. As someone new to relational databases I was hoping there was an easier way to achieve this.

So, I have a few questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way to define my tables such that all of this copying isn't necessary?
2. If this the best way, can you give an example of how you would set up the triggers (and associated functions)?
3. Do I need to worry about running out of space on the server as I create (potentially many) sets of triggers of this type?

Comment: Why do you want to create several tables with identical schema? Why not just one table for all ranks with foreign key?

Comment: Honestly, it hadn't occurred to me to structure it that way. Is it bad form to keep `ALTER`'ing a table as I add users?

Comment: In general, you should use a static schema that is only adjusted when the program changes. You should create only one rank table with foreign key to `items` and storing the _table number_ into a column.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're suggesting -- I don't know beforehand how many ranking columns I'll need, and I'm not sure what you mean by storing the 'table number'. Do you mean setting it up so the rank table has a column for rank and a column for which user those ranks correspond to? Like, `id | rank | userid`?

Comment: Yes, that's the relational approach.

Comment: My apologies if I'm being dense, but I don't see how that resolves the issue. Every time I add a new user, I'd need to re-copy all of the extant `id`'s and then add a new trigger to make sure the new user gets a copy of any `id`'s added later on.

Comment: You will notice the difference as soon as you make a request, e.g. the average rating of all users. Why do you want to store ranks, which the user has not entered?

Comment: Eventually each user will be required to rank every image so it seemed sensible to me to prepare enough rows for that from the start. Eventually I'll be performing actions that compare the ranking of each image between users so I'll need to be able to pull each users' ranking as an ordered list based on their individual rankings.